# Unable to access table cell after converting it to dataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, datatables, null

I am using dataTable from https://datatables.net/ for a large table displayed in my webpage. From js, I want to constantly update the table cells. But, when JS tries to set `document.getElementById('someCell').innerHTML=something`, it gives me this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

When I fire `document.getElementById('someCell')` from chrome console, I get null. But when I navigate to the page within dataTable where the the cell is displayed, the above command returns me the DOM object. Is there any way I can update table cells/rows which are hidden in some other pages due to DataTable's pagination?

Comment: Surprised to see a javascript question being unanswered on stackoverflow for so long...

Comment: Can anyone please solve my problem?

Comment: Did you check [Accessing table rows of second and further pages of a datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928932/jquery-accessing-table-rows-of-second-and-further-pages-of-a-datatable)?

Comment: You should manipulate DataTables data like this
`table.cells({ row: 2, column: 1 }).data("my value").draw();`

Answer (score 0):

You're using (DataTable) a JQuery plug-in.
-Why not using

**JQuery for accessing your cell :**

```
$('#someCellID').html('something');
```

Or (using respectively the row and column index) :

```
$('#tableID tbody tr:eq(1) td:eq(2)').html()
```

-OR even using the

**Datatable API**

```
table // your DataTable instance object
       .cells("#someCellID") // a jquery selector
       .data(); // the 'innerHTML'
```

Here's some links to the official documentation that might help you :

- [Get/Set value of a DataTable's cell](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().data())
- [Getting access to specific DataTable cell using JQuery selectors](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cells().data())
- [An already answered question (on DataTables.net forum)](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/49576/get-specific-cell-value-using-row-col-index-coordinates)